# How to remove the BOM from a h1 tag with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about removing the BOM in a tag using jQuery or just plain JavaScript?

```html
<h1 id="test">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>
```

As you can see I added the BOM's inbetween all the letters and it'll show up as normal on the website, bu I'm trying to directly trim the `&#65279;` with JavaScript.

How would I go about doing this as `.text()`, `.html()`, `.innerHTML()` would all return a normal string excluding the BOM

Comment: It would be a much better idea to remove it directly from the source, if possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can't. Let's just say I'm stuck with not being able to remove it from the source nor being able to even get to the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) and [.decodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp):

```js
//Javascript by Id:
var div = document.getElementById('test');
var pomString = encodeURI(div.innerHTML);
pomString = pomString.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, '');
div.innerHTML = decodeURI(pomString);


//Javascript by Class:
var divClass = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var pomStringClass = encodeURI(divClass[0].innerHTML);
pomStringClass = pomStringClass.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, '');
divClass[0].innerHTML = decodeURI(pomStringClass);


//JQuery by Id:
var divJquery = $('#jquery');
var pomJquery = encodeURI(divJquery.html());
pomJquery = pomJquery.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, '');
divJquery.html(decodeURI(pomJquery));


//JQuery by Class:
$('.jquery').each(function(){
  var pomJFilter = encodeURI($(this).html());
  pomJFilter = pomJFilter.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, '');
  $(this).html(decodeURI(pomJFilter));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Javascript by Id:

<h1 id="test">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>

<hr>

Javascript by Class:
<h1 class="test">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>
<h1 class="test">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>

<hr>

JQuery by Id:
<h1 id="jquery">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>

<hr>

JQuery by Class:
<h1 class="jquery">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>
<h1 class="jquery">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>
<h1 class="jquery">Jo&#65279;h&#65279;n D&#65279;oe</h1>
```

Comment: Was very useful, hope OP find it useful aswell +1

Comment: Very useful! Do you maybe know why this doesn't work if I were to use `getElementsByClassName` or `$()` for the `var` div?

Comment: You need to remember that searching one element by its class will return one array. You need to get the right element to make it work (or, if you want, create one loop to apply this function in all your elements with this class). If it is `<h1 class="test">`, you need to get the first element: `getElementsByClassName('test')[0]`.

Comment: I've updated some examples. Check if it match with your needs. :)

Comment: If I were to have multiple `h1`'s with the class `test`, could I use `$(".test").each(function(){ var div = $(this); //remove bom })` to loop through all of them?

Comment: Thanks for the examples!